# How to create a Device in Azure IoT Hub with go sdk

Tags: azure, go, azure-sdk-for-go

Can you point me to an example on which module is providing CRUD operations on Devices for Azure Iot Hub GO SDK?
I've checked https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples/tree/main but I've not found valid example.
In the specific, I'm interested in which go module is providing such APIs: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/create-or-update-identity?view=rest-iothub-service-2020-03-13)

Thanks!

Comment: what type of  CRUD operations  u would want to on azure Iot Hub device

Comment: I need to create/update a device, thanks

Comment: with rest API code with [go](https://i.imgur.com/6ab7cFu.png) created the azure IOT [hub device](https://i.imgur.com/yhFvnfh.png)  and updated [device](https://i.imgur.com/GEg5h7e.png)  should I share it in answer

Answer (score 0):

The code below demonstrates creating a device in Azure IoT Hub using Go and the REST API.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    sasToken :="SharedAccessSignature sr=<your IoT Hub name>.azure-devices.net/devices/<your device ID>&sig=<your signature>&se=<expiry time>&skn=<policy name>"


    
    deviceID := "sampath671"
    iotHubName := "certificate122ravi"


    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.azure-devices.net/devices/%s?api-version=2020-05-31-preview", iotHubName, deviceID)

    
    requestBody := map[string]interface{}{
        "deviceId": deviceID,
    }
    requestBodyBytes, err := json.Marshal(requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewBuffer(requestBodyBytes))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", sasToken )

    // Send the HTTP request
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()


    responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create device: %s", responseBody)
    }

    fmt.Println("Device created successfully!")


    fmt.Println("Response Body:", string(responseBody))
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

The code below updates the device status in Azure IoT Hub using the Azure IoT Hub REST API.

```js
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    
    sasToken :="SharedAccessSignature sr=<your IoT Hub name>.azure-devices.net/devices/<your device ID>&sig=<your signature>&se=<expiry time>&skn=<policy name>"

    
    deviceID := "sampath671"
    iotHubName := "certificate122ravi"

    
    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.azure-devices.net/devices/%s?api-version=2020-05-31-preview", iotHubName, deviceID)

    
    requestBody := map[string]interface{}{
        "deviceId":                  deviceID,
        "status":                    "disabled",                        
        "statusReason":              "Device disabled for maintenance",
        "connectionState":           "Disconnected",                    
        "lastActivityTime":          "2024-03-12T12:00:00Z",        
        "cloudToDeviceMessageCount": 10,                                
    }
    requestBodyBytes, err := json.Marshal(requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewBuffer(requestBodyBytes))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", sasToken)


    currentETag, err := getCurrentETag(deviceID, sasToken, iotHubName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    
    req.Header.Set("If-Match", currentETag)

    
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    
    responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to update device: %s", responseBody)
    }

    fmt.Println("Device updated successfully!")

    
    fmt.Println("Response Body:", string(responseBody))
}


func getCurrentETag(deviceID, sasToken, iotHubName string) (string, error) {
    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.azure-devices.net/devices/%s?api-version=2020-05-31-preview", iotHubName, deviceID)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    req.Header.Set("Authorization", sasToken)

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Failed to fetch device details: %s", resp.Status)
    }

    
    etag := resp.Header.Get("ETag")
    if etag == "" {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("ETag not found in response headers")
    }

    return etag, nil
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

The code below generates a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for Azure IoT Hub authentication. This token can be used by devices to authenticate with the Azure IoT Hub service from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/authenticate-authorize-sas?tabs=node).

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function generateSasToken(hostName, sharedAccessKeyName, sharedAccessKey, expiresInMinutes) {

const resourceUri = `${hostName}/devices`;

const expiry = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + expiresInMinutes * 60;

const toSign = encodeURIComponent(resourceUri) + '\n' + expiry;

  

const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(sharedAccessKey, 'base64'));

hmac.update(toSign);

const base64UriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(hmac.digest('base64'));

  

const token = `SharedAccessSignature sr=${encodeURIComponent(resourceUri)}&sig=${base64UriEncoded}&se=${expiry}&skn=${sharedAccessKeyName}`;

return token;

}

  

// Example usage

const hostName = "your-iot-hub-name>.azure-devices.net";

const sharedAccessKeyName = "your-shared-access-policy-name";

const sharedAccessKey = "your-shared-access-policy-key";

const expiresInMinutes = 60; // Token expiration time in minutes

  

const sasToken = generateSasToken(hostName, sharedAccessKeyName, sharedAccessKey, expiresInMinutes);

console.log("Generated SAS token:", sasToken);
```

**Output:**
[image]